# problem with hector_slam

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,I am using ROS INDIGO.I used hector_slam to build a 2D map from kinect data.Laser scan data is published on the topic /scan.I used the command `roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch` and getting "[ WARN] [1453709644.419967908]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.001889 seconds of waiting. This warning only". Please help me for solving this problem.

This is my launch file `hector.launch`

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225333/problem-with-hector_slam/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the answer

http://answers.ros.org/question/208584/hector-slam-does-not-work/

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-16**:
i did it like that........stilll getting the same error.......edited question adding my launch file.